# after using react-router-dom, the url has changed, but page didn't re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

i am using **react, redux, react-router** for my project and i have faced an issue.

whenever i use  **history.push()** or **Link to=''**  ,the targeted website will not render, but after refreshing it, everything seems to be normal again!

(adding {forcefresh: true} to ./history seems to solve the problem but are there any other ways to do it!)

As you can see, `isSignedIn` is null after redirect:

[image]

But after refresh, it will get `true` value.

My reducer:

```
import { SIGNED_IN, SIGNED_OUT } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  isSignedIn: null,
  userInfo: null,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGNED_IN:
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userInfo: action.payload }; //important parts!
    case SIGNED_OUT:
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: false, userId: null };
    default:
      // return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userInfo: action.payload };
      return initialState;
  }
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/0529bill/countable

Comment: /client/src/components/App/App.js for Router and Route setup

Comment: /client/scr/history.js for history setup

Comment: You should have posted the code in the question itself. But your router setup looks fine. What's the exact problem? Are you unable to go to any route using `history.push` or is it authentication problem i.e. you don't see home/dashboard page after login is done?

Comment: i have problems in detail in video format here :https://kapwi.ng/c/njymI7Aw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reducer, when you have a not-handled action, you're resetting the state (returning initial state):

```
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
```

that's why `isSignedIn` is getting null after redirect. because when there is a not-handled action, that will reset the state. (i took a look at your repo and there is an action called `FETCH_COUNTS` which is not handled.)

So change it to:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGNED_IN:
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userInfo: action.payload }; //important parts!
    case SIGNED_OUT:
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: false, userId: null };
    default:
      console.error('action is not handled!', action)
      return state; // <----- just return previous state when the actiontype is not recognized
  }
  return state
};
```

so that it won't reset the state when you have a not-handled action.

Comment: first of all, Thank you very much for your answer! but here comes another problem that whenever i try to create a new 'count', in src/components/Menucount it will create two EXACT same counts! and oddly, when i refresh the page, the second counts disappear! can you shed some light to this problem? and why is this happening! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @water the problem is that you're adding the new item 2 times. one when you dispatch `CREATE_COUNT` action, and another when you dispatch `FETCH_COUNTS` action. and solution is : on line 30 on `countReducers`, remove `...state,`, because it shouldn't add the fetched ones, it should replace them.